# Getting Retweet Count of a Given Tweet ID Number

Tags: python, api, twitter

I have used twitter search API to collect lots of tweets given a search keyword.  Now that I have this collection of tweets, I'd like to find out which tweet has been retweeted most.

Since search API does not have retweet_count, I have to find some other way to check how many times each tweet has been retweeted.  The only clue I have is that I have ID number for each tweet.  Is there any way I could use these ID numbers to figure out how many times each tweet has been retweeted??

I am using twitter module for python.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so, since one can either retweet using the retweet command or using a commented retweet. At least the second alternative generates a new tweet id

Answer (score 0):

I am currently studying twitter structure and had found out that is a field called tweet_count associated with each tweet as to # of times that particular original tweet has been retweeted